# WPF datepicker BlackoutDates on SelectedDateChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have two datepickers: "dpInputDate" and "dpDueDate". now DueDate must not be smaller than InputDate. So I used BlackoutDates.AddDatesInPast(); and it works fine when application starts. Now thing is when I change the selected date of dpInputDate, than dpDueDate automatically gets the same value. Problem is that the number of dates that are blacked out remains the same. Here is the code that I used:

```
 private void dpInputDate_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dpDueDate.SelectedDate = dpInputDate.SelectedDate;

        dpDueDate.BlackoutDates.Clear();
        dpDueDate.BlackoutDates.AddDatesInPast();
    }
```

How to manage this?

**UPDATE:**

```
private void dpDueDate_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (dpDueDate.SelectedDate != null)
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)dpDueDate.SelectedDate;
            dpDueDate.BlackoutDates.Clear();
            dpDueDate.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(1 / 1 / 2001), date));
        }
        else 
        {
            dpDueDate.BlackoutDates.AddDatesInPast();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddDatesInPast()` blocks out all dates from `DateTime.Now` (i.e. today), not from the `SelectedDate` backwards.

So you will need to calculate your own `CalendarDateRange`, and set the BlackoutDates to your new range.
There is an overload that takes two dates, which you can use for your purposes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672700(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hay i eddited my code but now I get this exception: "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: Value is not valid." . I realized it is becouse of my datepicker selected date format, but how to change it to right format?

Comment: Your use of the DateTime constructor isn't right. You want to use one of the overloads, such as `new DateTime(2001,1,1)`. But that will still make dates before 2001 available, which probably isn't what you want. Instead you could use `dpDueDate.BlackoutDates.Add(DateTime.MinValue,date)`

Comment: Ok tnx, I changed that but still get the same exception? How to deal with that?

Comment: "Parameter name: Value is not valid" doesn't look like an error with the code above ... there is no parameter called 'value' shown. Are you sure your error is here?

Comment: Yes, I found what the problem was... I had to subtract one day from dpDueDate.SelectedDate. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hang on a minute - your update has changed the event handler from dealing with `dpInputDate_SelectedDateChanged` to `dpDueDate_SelectedDateChanged`. Why? Change back to `dpInputDate_SelectedDateChanged`, and change back to setting your `dpDueDate.SelectedDate` to `dpInputDate.SelectedDate`.

Comment: Ok cool, if this has worked out for you mark it as answer! Cheers